# jsTree nodes don't expand/collapse

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jstree

Can't get jsTree nodes to expand collapse. I must be missing something very simple.

This is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jstree.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Refresh();
        });

        function Refresh() {
            $('#technologyTree').jstree({
                "json_data": {
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/TechnologyVersions/TechnologiesTreeAjax",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "dataType": "json"
                    }
                },

                "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],

                "themes": {
                    "theme": "default",
                    "dots": true,
                    "icons": true,
                    "url": " <%= Url.Content("~/Content/jsTree/themes/default/style.css") %> "
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

I can see the tree populated correctly and the json result from the controller seems correct. However when I click on those expand/collapse arrows nothing happens.

Comment: does it not require jquery to be loaded before the javascript file for the tree?

Comment: @cpoDesign I skipped posting the 10000 javascript library includes to conserve space :P but true jquery was relevant here. I posted what was the problem bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that conflict with jQuery validation plugin. Upgrading to latest version of jQuery validation plugin solves the problem.

[JsTree conflicts with jquery.validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079425/jstree-conflicts-with-jquery-validate)